# How can I record a video like output of top command for set time period?

Tags: command-line, process, top, desktop-recording

The `top` command outputs a kind of live view of processes and their use of resources in a system.

I'd like to start a program on a server installation, which starts a variety of different processes, with non-predictable PIDs, and capture the changing output of `top`, without having to rely on an ssh connection from a desktop environment. Preferably I'd like to be able to 'replay' this in the same CLI environment, as if it were a video, but could acceptably move the file elsewhere to view it like this.

Is there a way, **using command line only, from a direct terminal on a server installation,** that I can record this output for a defined time period? Either by entering a value for time, or by manually starting and stopping the recording process.

Comment: You can script a `ps` command which can give the same info of `top` and save the output to a file... or am I misreading your question?

Comment: @Rmano I was envisaging a sort of video like representation of it, but saving output to a file with associated time information seems a useful way to view the data.

Comment: @Arronical: TREE's answer should accomplish exactly what you want...

Comment: Related (but different) problem: [Stop reading process output in Python without hang?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4417962)

Comment: `ttyrec -e top`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the 'script' and 'scriptreplay' utilities to accomplish this.

1. run script with the --timing option:

   script --timing=top.timing topscript
2. execute the top command, let it run as long as you want
3. exit top using q or control-c.
4. exit the script session with control-D (EOF) or by typing exit
5. run scriptreplay to replay the script:

   scriptreplay top.timing topscript

Comment: This is great, thanks! I did find that for some reason the timing file came out as `=top.timing` using your example, if I renamed it and tried to use it as input to `scriptreplay`, nothing happened.

Comment: I have re-tested with the provided commands, and they work for me. Make sure you include both dashes before timing in the first command.

Comment: I'd been using `-t` instead of `--timing`. With `--timing` there's no preceeding '='.

Answer (score 6):

The regular mode of operation of `top` is not suitable for saving the output in a file.

You can use the `-b` (batch) mode of `top` along with appropriate time interval for checking (`-d`) and the number of iterations for count (`-n`).

You can also mention specific PIDs (`-p`) to check only.

For example:

```
top -b -d 5 -n 3 -p 1089,2345 >output.txt
```

will run `top` in batch mode, will do 3 iterations after 5 seconds each, and will only monitor two mentioned PIDs (1089,2345). The output will be saved in `output.txt`.

Change the values to fit your need.

Comment: I was hoping to see a video-like representation, but I suppose I could script a loop which saves batch mode output of top into separate files. Then create a viewing loop, which displays the each files contents separated by the same time increment, to recreate the effect of the regular operating mode of `top`. Thanks for pointing my head in the right direction :)

Comment: @Arronical Yeah if that is your plan..

Answer (score 1):

This is not *exactly* the same as `top`, but you can use this script:

```
while true; do
echo 
echo $(date)
echo
ps -eo pid,user,pri,ni,vsize,rss,stat,pcpu,pmem,time,wchan --sort=-pcpu | head -20
sleep 5 
done  > ps.log
```

You will have more or less the `top` info in the file `ps.log`. For details about the `ps` command, see `man ps`.